# Creating HTML Snapshot for AngularJS App for Search Engine Crawling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

First of all let me tell you what i want to do.

I want to index my Website which is made in Angular JS, for this i had read all documents or articles from google for this kind of purpose.

And what i found is that :

I need to convert my angular js url to friendly url with `html5Mode` or `hashbag` mode.

like : `http://www.example.com/#/about` to `http://www.example.com/#!/about` or just `http://www.example.com/about`

using `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

So when any crawler will come on my website say that `Googlebot` will come and it will see my url as `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/about` so now i need to serve this request to static html page....Right??

Now my question is **how can i generate this html static page with php framework and this html should create automatically only after its content is fully loaded means If angular js is loading data with $http request then this html will only generated after all data will loaded in html template.**

I can serve this html to crawler only if this can be generated automatically.

I have tested locally by creating some html page manually and check that if request will come with `_escaped_fragment_` parameter then it will server that particular static html page.

But i'm not able to find way for that i will create html page for particular angular js request with php framework.

I dont want to use any `npm` services.I want to create it fully in `php` and/or any `jQuery Plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from needing a server you redirect your escaped fragment requests to, where the server has taken HTML snapshots after the various views have been rendered, which can then be fed to Googlebot, etc, don't forget you'll also need a setting in your existing web server (such as Apache or IIS) to redirect to the new server handling your escaped fragment.

I appreciate you're looking for a PHP solution, and don't want to use an NPM one like the prerender or seoserver packages, but I want to throw an alternative and easier solution your way: Use an existing hosted solution such as https://www.seo4ajax.com/ or https://prerender.io/ instead. They'll host an SEO server for you that can crawl your site, and typically this is free unless you've got a huge data-driven site with more than a few hundred pages. Less load for you, no need to run yet another server, and you get some nice admin panels to look at what crawlers have hit the SEO redirect, etc.

Broadly speaking, you'll need the meta tag in your HTML you mention, and these settings in your AngularJS config:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

Then some custom redirect settings such as in an .htaccess file if your existing server is Apache, which these sites will give you, and you can copy and paste.

Comment: Hey..thanks and i agree that i need to use solutions like https://www.seo4ajax.com/ or https://prerender.io/ but this services will provide me their services and i need to setup as per that but i want to generate this snapshot on my server using my own programming and then want to serve to google.